# How to disable closing a React Navigation drawer on overlay click

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I don't want to close drawers if the overlay is clicked. Is it possible to disable that? Or, better, remove the overlay all together? Currently, I am just making its color `transparent` but it would be better if I could just get rid of the overlay.

---

So I have a button on a screen I want to be able to click:

[image]

But when the Drawer expands, it covers the screen with an overlay. So when I try to click on my button, it clicks on the overlay instead which closes the drawer ‍♂️:

[image]

If I just turn off `swipeEnabled` then it just gets rid of the gesture ability, but the overlay remains. If I add `drawerStyle: { width: '100%' }` then the Drawer takes up the entire width of the screen and the button is still unclickable:

[image]

Ideally, I would be able to expand a Drawer, and just get rid of the overlay all together, so I can have the Drawer open **and** click on the button at the same time:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please follow like this:

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
...
<Drawer.Navigator
 screenOptions={{
  drawerStyle: { width: '100%' },
  swipeEnabled: false
 }}
>
 //...
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

You can also specify drawerType option.

```
screenOptions={{
 drawerType='back'//'front' | 'back' | 'slide' | 'permanent'
}}
```

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't work. It just makes the drawer container take up 100% width (so you still can't click on stuff on the main screen).

Comment: so you can disable closing drawer menu and get overlay removed. then what did you want more?

Comment: I want to have the drawer expanded and still be able to click the screen behind it.

Comment: The drawer screen will get focus when it expands. It's impossible 2 screens get input at the same time.

Comment: I don't want the overlay. I just want the Drawer expanded and the ability to still interact with the screen underneath. Sorry, maybe I'm not explaining it very well. I've attached some pictures to the original question.

Comment: I did some more research and it doesn't seem possible. They use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-drawer-layout under the hood and they don't expose a way to tweak its `Overlay` component styles from React Navigation.